# Numbers under a note (guitar)

Tags: notation, acoustic-guitar, tuplet

Hi I am a guitar beginner, can someone help me to understand what does that number (3 under notes) mean?[image]

Comment: You may want to learn how to take screenshots for future question. For Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027213/windows-10-open-snipping-tool-and-take-a-screenshot. For MacOS: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361. For iOS: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289

Answer (score 1):

Since you're a beginner, I would assume you're working in 4/4.

If that's the case, the "3" that connects the eighth notes makes them an eighth note triplet. This means that you fit the E, D, & C all into the timing of one quarter note (in 4/4).

This video explains it fairly well for a beginner.

When I first started learning how to count, it helped if you say "triplet" (pronounce "trip-ah-let" for the timing) in the time of one beat. (So you would tap your foot or finger or have a metronome, and make the syllables individual notes. i.e. in your example, "Trip" = E, "ah" = D, & "let" = C.) That being said, once you're comfortable, you should break that habit and just get used to the timing itself.

If you're new to reading music and still don't fully grasp note values/length in a given time signature, you should really start with the basics (whole, half, quarter, eighth, etc.) then you can tackle tuplets.

Hopefully that makes some semblance of sense.

Comment: The mnemonic I remember was "_one-trip-let, two-trip-let, three-trip-let, four-trip-let_"

Comment: I've never heard of that one lol, but it is definitely the same concept. I guess it doesn't quite matter as long as it is 3 syllables that you can fit into the space of one 1/4 note.

Answer (score 0):

Diffuclt to be sure without even a complete measure and given the poor image quality, but this is most probably a *triplet*, i. e. the 3 eighth notes add up to one quarter note.